# What software can I use to simulate a deck of cards for playing online?

Tags: tools, online-roleplaying

I'm going to be running a game over a Google+ hangout, and the game needs a deck of cards that all of the players will draw from, keeping some of the draws hidden. I've searched around but most of the things I've seen replace the cards after they're drawn.

I'm looking specifically for something web based so that I don't have to require the players to install any software.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Roll20](http://roll20.net/) is another online tabletop - recently out of kickstarter - that operates with Google+ Hangouts. It's got good card support, including recently added hands and more features. The [changelog](http://community.roll20.net/discussion/201/changelog-updated-625#Item_12) has more details, including:

> - Better support for multiple decks.
> - Switched from the "drag upward" draw motion to just "click" to draw.
> - You can now deal cards to players, who have "hands" to hold the cards
> - Cards can be dragged and dropped directly from the deck onto the tabletop, or from player hands onto the tabletop, turning them into
>     drawings that can be moved, resized, etc.
> - Cards can be "picked up" from the table to your hand by right-clicking and selecting "Take Card".
> - Cards can be flipped by right-clicking and choosing "Flip Card." In addition if you hold down Shift while dropping a card onto the
>     tabletop it will start face-down instead of face-up.
> - Players can re-order the cards in their hands.
> - Players can trade cards and steal from each other (there are dialog boxes for confirming both).
> - You can now designate that a deck has "infinite cards", then just add one card and it will always be drawn, no need to re-shuffle the
>     deck.

There is a [video overview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKTcYrvIB-k&feature=youtu.be) as well.

Answer (score 1):

One I've played (but never actually engineered myself) is called [VASSAL](http://www.vassalengine.org/).  A guy I know playtests his card games using this program which includes your standard two deck versus and even deckbuilding games.  We are in two different countries so it definitely has networking capability.  You create a module and set all the card properties (where they go, visibility, etc.) and can upload all of your art.  Where it gets a little manual is things like counters and costs and what-not.

Comment: I'm looking for something web-based so that the players don't have to install anything.

Comment: Vassal requires a free install.